# MVVM Architecture Screen Rotation Issues

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, retrofit2, android-mvvm, mutablelivedata

I have been trying to make a simple program where I will get data from Retrofit API calling into RecyclerView using MVVM architecture with JAVA, but I am not getting any data from Retrofit API into recycler view until or unless I rotate the screen of the phone. I am using asynchronous API calling using Retrofit and my research shows that so many people have this problem of not getting data until or unless screen rotation happens but there was not even a single solution for this. I am also using MutableLiveData<> and LiveData<> to keep track of any change or new data from API.

I am also using MutableLiveData<> and LiveData<> to keep track of any change or new data from API. I have applied onChangeListener() on the adapter of the RecyclerView

Comment: can you please provide us with some code sample which is used for calls making and how you are working with the rotation issues?

Comment: @Andrew I am making an API call inside the Repository which then connected to ViewModel and the result then sent to MainActivity from ViewModel and I am observing the method of ViewModel which were making the API call from Repository. after all these I notify the adapter of recycler view. If you have. I am making asynchronous retrofit API call.

Comment: Too broad. Consider posting a minimal reproducible code example.